# Why does my model reorient itself when I render it?

Tags: modeling, rendering

It was facing in Y+ direction, so i turned it to X+ direction so that it fits my scene, but when i render it turns back around it sound stupid but i am not joking!

Here is the [File](http://download1649.mediafire.com/lyr91i9q1z8g/qa9p2puo20zc7vj/ALL+CARS.blend)

Answer (score 6):

You have inserted keyframes , the viewport is displaying frame 2922 and you are rendering frame 0.

you can change what frame you want to render in the render settings.

to clear all keyframes select all objects and press Alt+I

Answer (score -1):

Press NumPad 0 to enter camera view. Move and rotate the camera to change the rendered view. In the properties panel (shortcut N in the 3D window) you can lock the camera to the view, to adjust the shot.

Comment: Does not address problem.